# Looking for source(s) on cuisine and humorism theory for how they've changed over time

Tags: food

Just to preface: no, I do not believe in humorism.

I was watching a show a few years ago where the hosts ate food from different time periods. They remarked how pork and applesauce  were an odd combination (though delicious) which came about because of humorism, where apples and pork represented two different humors.

Intrigued, I have repeatedly attempted to look up more information on the various humors associated with foods. I have found lists in places, with no sources to back them up (which makes me suspicious). I have spoken with historians and museum curators who say that such books exist, but they haven't the foggiest where to find them.

As near as I can find, it is generally agreed that food was associated with specific humors. But I can not find any scholarly texts on the subject, nor can I find lists of foods associated with the various humors which actually can date itself back to when humorism was still in vogue.

What intrigues me is how the associations for foodstuffs may have changed over the centuries, and how assignments were made for new foodstuffs. Food-associated humorism was a very long running theory, how did it change over time, specifically with how the foods themselves were perceived?

Comment: This may be a better fit for Seasoned Advice SE, the food site.

Comment: I think the association of particular foods with particular humours goes back to [Galen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen). You might want to look at [Galen: On the Properties of Foodstuffs](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NmZTpZTN-EoC) as a starting point.

Comment: @TomAu already tried there to no avail.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I have altered it to bring it a bit more in line I think.

Comment: [This passage](https://books.google.hu/books?id=kLbb7_f-ZUAC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=humeur+et+saveur&source=bl&ots=TfyTskIr1d&sig=3JPxDLieP8Z0Cd1NucOJBzNWr7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4h5rwpNbVAhXBIJoKHdi3BTwQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=humeur%20et%20saveur&f=false) from a book in French hints at it tracing all the way back to [On Ancient Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Ancient_Medicine).

Comment: I think the revised question is in scope.